# How to remove children in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the equivalent of the following JQuery code in JavaScript:

```
$('div').children().remove();
```

I tried following but it says length is not defined:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div').childNodes;
for(var i=0; i< nodes.length; i++) {

         nodes[i].remove();

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfi/RyGKV/604/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct cross-browser way to remove elements in pure JavaScript is:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

So following your example the solution is this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i],
        children = node.childNodes;

    for (var j = children.length; j--;) {
        node.removeChild(children[j]);
    }
}
```

However, better option to remove all children is to do it in `while` loop:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/N6RM4/1/

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('div').childNodes` has no length, but `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` does have a length

Comment: @user3421904 Yes, because `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` of `<div>` elements and you should iterate over it.

Comment: Does this detach any jQuery events on those elements? Or should you do something special?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher All jQuery events are stored in element's data object under property `events`. So if you attach events directly to the elements (meaning no event delegation), then destroying the element destroys all the data defined for it.

Comment: @VisioN: The `Node.remove()` method is available in modern browsers. There's a problem with your solution in that you're going to skip some nodes because the `.childNodes` list is constantly being reindexed beacuse of the removals.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: No, it does *not* detach any jQuery events or data as VisioN claimed. This would cause a memory leak if there was any jQuery events or data associated with those elements.

Comment: @cookiemonster You are right regarding the indices, thanks! I completely forgot about that, providing the solution from the top of my head. The inversed loop will do the trick.

Comment: The jQuery aspect should be realized as well. This should never be done if you're using jQuery unless you know for certain that there's no data cached for the elements and their ancestors. jQuery uses its data cache for several different things, so that can be tricky. Not sure if OP is using jQuery or not.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a element-list and you have to specify the index (in your case [0])

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].childNodes;
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyGKV/607/)

Answer (score 0):

Check `document.getElementsByTagName('div')`

It returns a `NodeList`

This has no member called `childNodes`

To remove all childnodes of all divs, you need to iterate over these nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/m8QH2/2/)

HTML

```
<button id="adds" onclick="add()">add</button>
<button id="removes" onclick="del()">remove</button>
<form>
    <div id="myList">
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
function del(){
    var list=document.getElementById("myList");
    if (list.childNodes.length > 2){
        list.removeChild(list.childNodes[list.childNodes.length-1]);
    }
}


function add(){
    var par=document.createElement("div");
    var chi = document.createElement('div');    
    chi.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"></input>';
    par.appendChild(chi);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(par);
}
```